# 10401 Order total is invalid ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, webforms, paypal-sandbox

I am writing a shop app using ASP.NET(Web-Form) and WingtipToys tutorial from msdn.

I have a problem when I am using paypal button. I have error:

```
10401
Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
Order total is invalid.
```

This is part of code where's something wrong i think:

```
public bool ShortcutExpressCheckout(string amt, ref string token, ref string retMsg)
{
    if (bSandbox)
    {
        pEndPointURL = pEndPointURL_SB;
        host = host_SB;
    }

    string returnURL = "https://localhost:44317/Checkout/CheckoutReview.aspx";
    string cancelURL = "https://localhost:44317/Checkout/CheckoutCancel.aspx";

    NVPCodec encoder = new NVPCodec();
    encoder["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";
    encoder["RETURNURL"] = returnURL;
    encoder["CANCELURL"] = cancelURL;
    encoder["BRANDNAME"] = "Shop";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = amt;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"] = amt;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"] = "PLN";

    // Get the Shopping Cart Products
    using (Shop.Logic.ShoppingCartActions myCartOrders = new Shop.Logic.ShoppingCartActions())
    {
        List<ElementKoszyka> myOrderList = myCartOrders.GetCartItems();

        for (int i = 0; i < myOrderList.Count; i++)
        {
            encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME" + i] = myOrderList[i].Produkt.nazwa_produkt.ToString();
           // string tmp = Math.Round(myOrderList[i].Produkt.cena, 2).ToString();
           // encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" + i] = Math.Round(myOrderList[i].Produkt.cena, 2).ToString();
            encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" + i] = "22.50";
            encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY" + i] = myOrderList[i].ilosc.ToString();
        }
    }

    string pStrrequestforNvp = encoder.Encode();
    string pStresponsenvp = HttpCall(pStrrequestforNvp);

    NVPCodec decoder = new NVPCodec();
    decoder.Decode(pStresponsenvp);

    string strAck = decoder["ACK"].ToLower();
    if (strAck != null && (strAck == "success" || strAck == "successwithwarning"))
    {
        token = decoder["TOKEN"];
        string ECURL = "https://" + host + "/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout" + "&token=" + token;
        retMsg = ECURL;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        retMsg = "ErrorCode=" + decoder["L_ERRORCODE0"] + "&" +
            "Desc=" + decoder["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"] + "&" +
            "Desc2=" + decoder["L_LONGMESSAGE0"];
        return false;
    }
}
```

Total order is assign permanently (22.50) and still have a problem.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The price is being assigned at

```
encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" + i] = "22.50";
```

Maybe it should be something like

```
encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" + i] = myOrderList[i].Produkt.nazwa_price.ToString();
```

Comment: Still same problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okey, problem solved. I have to change amt to decimal in different class.

So the correct format for paypal order is: "xx.xx"

Answer (score 0):

If your computer uses the decimal komma then you should change your assignment to:

```
encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" + i] = (myOrderList[i].Produkt.nazwa_price.ToString()).Replace(",",".");
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. The reason is different decimal formatting in Poland. 
To see which line to change look for  // <---------SOLUTION------------> comment in code below:

```
public bool ShortcutExpressCheckout(string amt, ref string token, ref string retMsg)
{
    if (bSandbox)
    {
        pEndPointURL = pEndPointURL_SB;
        host = host_SB;
    }

    string returnURL = "https://localhost:44304/Checkout/CheckoutReview.aspx";
    string cancelURL = "https://localhost:44304/Checkout/CheckoutCancel.aspx";

    amt = amt.Replace(",",".");  // <---------SOLUTION------------>

    NVPCodec encoder = new NVPCodec();
    encoder["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";
    encoder["RETURNURL"] = returnURL;
    encoder["CANCELURL"] = cancelURL;
    encoder["BRANDNAME"] = "Wingtip Toys Sample Application";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = amt;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT"] = amt;
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
    encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"] = "PLN";

    // Get the Shopping Cart Products
    using (WingtipToys.Logic.ShoppingCartActions myCartOrders = new WingtipToys.Logic.ShoppingCartActions())
    {
        List<CartItem> myOrderList = myCartOrders.GetCartItems();

        for (int i = 0; i < myOrderList.Count; i++)
        {
            encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME" + i] = myOrderList[i].Product.ProductName.ToString();
            encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" + i] = myOrderList[i].Product.UnitPrice.ToString().Replace(",", ".");  // <---------SOLUTION------------>
            encoder["L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY" + i] = myOrderList[i].Quantity.ToString();
        }
    }

    string pStrrequestforNvp = encoder.Encode();
    string pStresponsenvp = HttpCall(pStrrequestforNvp);

    NVPCodec decoder = new NVPCodec();
    decoder.Decode(pStresponsenvp);

    string strAck = decoder["ACK"].ToLower();
    if (strAck != null && (strAck == "success" || strAck == "successwithwarning"))
    {
        token = decoder["TOKEN"];
        string ECURL = "https://" + host + "/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout" + "&token=" + token;
        retMsg = ECURL;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        retMsg = "ErrorCode=" + decoder["L_ERRORCODE0"] + "&" +
            "Desc=" + decoder["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"] + "&" +
            "Desc2=" + decoder["L_LONGMESSAGE0"];
        return false;
    }
}
```